# Demonstration of $\mathring{E}=(\mathbb{R}\setminus{\partial{E}})$ such that $E\subset{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: general-topology

I have some difficulties to understand this demonstration. Can you explain to me some lines.

**Proposition** 
$$\mathring{E}=(\mathbb{R}\setminus{\partial{E}}) : E\subset{\mathbb{R}}$$

**Demonstration**
\begin{aligned}
x\in\mathbb{R} \land x\in\overline{E} 
\iff& x\in\overline{E} \land x\in{\mathbb{R}\setminus{\partial{E}}} \\\\
\iff& \forall{r}>0 : (x-r, x+r) \cap E \ne \emptyset \land \\
\neg(&\forall{r}>0 : (x-r, x+r) \cap{E} \ne \emptyset \land \\
&\forall{r}>0:(x-r, x+r) \cap{(\mathbb{R}\setminus{E})} \ne \emptyset) \\\\
\iff& \forall{r}>0 : (x-r, x+r) \cap E \ne \emptyset \land \\
(&\exists{r}>0 : (x-r, x+r) \cap{E} \ne \emptyset \lor \\
&\exists{r}>0: (x-r, x+r) \cap{(\mathbb{R}\setminus{E})} \ne \emptyset) \\\\
\iff& \forall{r}>0 : (x-r, x+r) \cap E \ne \emptyset \land \\
&\exists{r}>0 : (x-r, x+r) \cap{(\mathbb{R}\setminus{E})} \ne \emptyset \\\\
\iff& \forall{r}>0 : (x-r, x+r) \cap E \ne \emptyset \land \\
&\exists{r}>0 : (x-r, x+r) \subset E \\\\
\iff& \exists{r}>0 : (x-r, x+r) \subset E \\\\
\iff& \mathring{E}
\end{aligned}

> I don't understand why this can be true: 
>   $$\exists{r}>0:(x-r, x+r) \cap{(\mathbb{R}\setminus{E})} \ne \emptyset \iff \exists{r}>0: (x-r, x+r) \subset E $$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This statement is false: take $E = [0,1]$, then $\partial E = \{0,1\}$ and its complement is $(-\infty,0) \cup (0,1) \cup (1,\infty) \neq E^{\circ} = (0,1)$. What does hold: $E^{\circ} = E \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \partial E)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That implication is not true. I believe you are misreading the statement.

This is one statement

> $$ \forall{r}>0 : (x-r, x+r) \cap E \ne \emptyset \land \\
> (\exists{r}>0 : (x-r, x+r) \cap{E} \ne \emptyset \lor \\
> \exists{r}>0: (x-r, x+r) \cap{(\mathbb{R}\setminus{E})} \ne \emptyset) $$

And this is the other.

> $$ \forall{r}>0 : (x-r, x+r) \cap E \ne \emptyset \land \\
> \exists{r}>0 : (x-r, x+r) \cap{(\mathbb{R}\setminus{E})} \ne \emptyset $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're rassuring me. I thought I was crazy.